# how to change pattern in file's line

Tags: regex, bash

I have file with one line:

```
22:50133-MM:MM1,52-MM:MM2;23:254940-MM:MM1,63-MM:MM2;24:15574-MM:MM1,65-MM:MM2;
```

I need find this part of line `24:15574-MM` and then replace the number `15574` to another one. The number can be any length.

I want to use bash for it, but I have no idea how to do it.
How can I do it?  Please help.

Comment: I suggest to use `sed`‘s `s` command: `s/regexp/replacement/`. See `man sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for *I want to use `bash` for it*, here is an attempt using only native operators in it; using the `regEx` feature with its `~` operator (supported from `bash 3.0` onwards) .

Assuming your file has only one single line in it, you can do the following steps,

- The  below commands can be run directly on the command-line (or)
- wrap-it up in a shell script with the `bash` she-bang(`#!/bin/bash`).

Capturing the file contents for `regEx` match using the `<file`, which stores the entire file contents in the variable.

```
fileContent=$(<file)
[[ $fileContent =~ .*24:([[:digit:]]+)-MM.* ]] && replacement="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
replaceValue=5555
printf "%s\n" "${fileContent/$replacement/$replaceValue}"
```

For your input file, the commands produce a result

```
22:50133-MM:MM1,52-MM:MM2;23:254940-MM:MM1,63-MM:MM2;24:5555-MM:MM1,65-MM:MM2;
```

Comment: Thanks Inian. Your solution is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily achieved using `sed` command with `-i` option:

```
new_number=11111
sed -i "s/24:\(15574\)-MM/24:$new_number-MM/" /tmp/test.txt
```

---

`/tmp/test.txt` - replace with your current filepath

`new_number` - is a variable for replacement number

---

To replace using regexp pattern use the following command with `-E` option enabled(extended regular expressions mode):

`sed -i -E "s/24:(15574)-MM/24:$new_number-MM/" /tmp/test.txt`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the number (15574) must be regexp. How can I use regexp for it?